# Xamarin.forms.ListView - GroupHeader - Can we draw outside parent's bounds

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.listview

I made a custom Listview of events on Xamarin.Forms, grouped by date. I want to add a icon in my GroupHeader Template like this :

[image: What I want]

For iOS : No problem, my icon is drew outside his parent's bounds. 
For Android : The icon doesn't exceed his parent's bounds, i have this :

[image: What I have on Android]

Can you help me ? Is it possible for Android ?
Here is my XAML Code :

```
<!-- calendar + list -->
<StackLayout x:Name="stackPrincipal" Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Margin="0" Spacing="0">

    <!-- CALENDAR -->
    <Controls:WeekCalendarView x:Name="weekCalendarView" ReloadList="ReloadMondaniteListe"></Controls:WeekCalendarView>

    <!-- LIST -->
    <ListView x:Name="ListViewMondanite"
          Margin="0"
          RowHeight="60"
          HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
          IsGroupingEnabled="True"
          BackgroundColor="Transparent"
          HasUnevenRows="True"
          ItemTapped="ListMondanite_TappedAsync"
          SeparatorColor="{StaticResource separatorDark}"
          GroupDisplayBinding="{Binding Key}">
        <ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell Height="30">
                    <AbsoluteLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource secondaryColor}" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">

                        <Label Text="{Binding Key}" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1.01,1.01" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" Margin="20,0,0,0" VerticalOptions="Center" Style="{StaticResource TextSmallWhite}" />
                        <Controls:CircleImageButton AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.9,0.5,80,80" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional" VerticalOptions="Center" 
                                                    Padding="0,-20,0,-20" ImageSource="{local:ImgFromRes Top500.Images.Events.ic_event_calendrier.png}" />
                    </AbsoluteLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Controls:ListMondaniteTemplate></Controls:ListMondaniteTemplate>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

I've tried : Absolute Layout, Relative Layout, Grid ... none works.

Thanks you !

Comment: Hello, have you solved it?

Comment: Hello, no I haven't :(